# How to setup Git Repo for Laravel Project to run after Cloning?

Tags: php, git, laravel, gitlab

How do you to setup a Git Repo for a Laravel Project to run after cloning from a remote host like Gitlab, Guthub or Bitbucket?  After cloning a Laravel repo to a local computer php artisan serve gives this error 'PHP Warning:  require(D:\MyGitLab\laravel-project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory '.  This means simply cloning does not work.  What is the solution?  I added all files and directories to origin repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

php artisan key:generate

That should work.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make a copy of .env.example to .env file.
2. Make database and link it from .env file.
3. Run `composer update` command
4. Run `php artisan key:generate` command
5. Install Bower, NPM or any other front end package if you are using.
6. Run `php artisan migrate` command.
7. Run `php artisan serve` command.

You are good to go!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

`composer update`

first to install package dependency and run

`php artisan serve`

and run

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: only solves artisan serve but 127.0.0.1:8000 says 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.'